# log4j and daylight savings

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

We encountered an issue with our logs after North America switched to to daylight savings time. The log time didn't change to reflect the clock "springing forward" until the log rollover policy caused it to reset.

We use the following Pattern Layout and Policies within a RollingRandomAccessFile appender:

```
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d{ISO8601} traceId=%X{X-B3-TraceId} spanId=%X{X-B3-SpanId} [%-15.20t] %-5p %-20c{1.} : %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            <!-- 100MB limit before log file is rolled over -->
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
        </Policies>
```

Could anyone point me to the expected behaviour here that log4j supports for this type of situation? We're currently on log4j version 2.4.1

Comment: Consider using UTC timestamps for your logs. Then you never have a "time change" issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely caused by an [issue with DST](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1849)  in the `FixedDateFormat` class that Log4j2 uses for the predefined date formats (all formats that have a name, like DEFAULT, ABSOLUTE, COMPACT, DATE, ISO8601, and ISO8601_BASIC).

The issue has been fixed and will be included in the upcoming Log4j 2.8.2 release.

Comment: As recorded here I guess: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1849

Answer (score 2):

In similar situations, it has been suggested to add the TZ to your pattern. Since you're in Belfast (and I assume London is more correct? from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)), try:

```
<Pattern>%d{ISO8601}{Europe/London} traceId=%X{X-B3-TraceId} spanId=%X{X-B3-SpanId} [%-15.20t] %-5p %-20c{1.} : %m%n</Pattern>
```

From [Log4J 2 Layouts](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html):

> d{pattern}
>
> date{pattern}
>
> Outputs the date of the logging event. The date conversion specifier may be followed by a set of braces containing a date and time pattern string per SimpleDateFormat .
>
> The predefined formats are DEFAULT, ABSOLUTE, COMPACT, DATE, ISO8601, and ISO8601_BASIC.
>
> **You can also use a set of braces containing a time zone id per java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone**. If no date format specifier is given then the DEFAULT format is used.

```
Pattern             Example
%d{DEFAULT}         2012-11-02 14:34:02,781
%d{ISO8601}         2012-11-02T14:34:02,781
%d{ISO8601_BASIC}   20121102T143402,781
%d{ABSOLUTE}        14:34:02,781
%d{DATE}            02 Nov 2012 14:34:02,781
%d{COMPACT}         20121102143402781
%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS}    14:34:02,781
%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}    02 Nov 2012 14:34:02,781
%d{HH:mm:ss}{GMT+0} 18:34:02
%d{UNIX}            1351866842
%d{UNIX_MILLIS}     1351866842781
```

Possible duplicate: [Configure DST(Daylight Savings Time) in log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857827/configure-dstdaylight-savings-time-in-log4j) - take note of the additional information regarding TZUpdater, if it's appropriate for you.

Additional related bug report: [How does log4j2 handle daylight savings](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-698)